# Using similarity score within lstm embedding for attention based mechanism

Tags: machine-learning, transformer, attention

Yesterday, I found [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34150797/) fascinating paper about predicting various clinical conditions using an attention based LSTM. I don't have any practical experience with attention mechanism or transformers, which might be the reason why I struggle to understand why this approach work. Well, let me first try to summarize what the authors accomplished

[image]

As a first step, the use some sort of model to predict the future course of some important clinical variables. Their outcome is denoted by $X_0...X_t$. As a second step, these features (no timeseries data!) are passed into a transformer like architecture:

- as an embedding step, the predicted clinical variables along with some static ones are passed to an LSTM that computes several hidden states: $H_0...H_t$
- the attention step receives  $h_0...h_t$. For computing the contribution of each hidden state, the author states that each hidden state $h_i$ is passed to a function that computes the similarity between $h_i$ and $h_t$, that is the last hidden state of the lstm. From each resulting score $s_i$, a weight is computed with the softmax function $$w_i = \frac{exp(s_i)}{\sum_{j=0}^texp(s_j)}$$. The context vector cv is then calculated by computing the weighted sum of hidden states.
- the decoder receives the context vector concatenated with $h_t$ and computes the output using two dense layers.

What I don't understand are two things:

1. Is it legit to use a lstm as embedding, while the input is no time series data but independent features?
2. In the presented approach, the weight of an hidden state $h_i$ depends on the similarity to the output of the lstm, i.e. $h_t$. But isn't an attention-based architecture used precisely to let every input variable contribute equally to the output, and to combat lstm's problem of struggling with long dependencies? With long inputs, i guess that $h_0$ tends to be likely to have larger differences from $h_t$ than, e.g. $h_{t-1}$ simply because it is more in the past. If this is true, $h_t$ automatically would receive a smaller weight.

Are my thoughts correct or have I missed something?